# Generic function where second parameter depends on first

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible in C# to create a generic function where the first parameter is an enum (one of several so it has to be generic I guess) and the second parameter is forced to be a value from the enum selected as the first parameter? I understand generics has to be used but I can't think of how to write such an expression, or if it's even possible.

**Edit: Added code example**
I know that this code example doesn't work but it illustrates a little in the direction I was thinking.

```
public List<int> Call<EnumValue>(Type enumType, EnumValue enumValue) where EnumValue : Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumType))
{
  // Something    
}
```

Comment: You can't even constrain a generic method/class to only apply to Enums.

Comment: Thats right, the closest I think you can get is:
    public void enumFunction<t>(t enumObject)
Where t is the type of enum, and enumObject is an instance of it.

Comment: do you mean the first parameter has to be an enum Type and the second one is a value of that type? Or do you just mean both parameters are values of the same enum type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to have a compile-time constraint like that. The best you could do is a run-time check:

```
public List<int> Call<TEnum>(Type enumType, TEnum enumValue) 
{
    if(!enumType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEnum)))
        throw new ArgumentException();

    // Something
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Although I'm not sure why you need to pass the `Type`, if it *has to be* same type as the other parameter anyway. Couldn't you get rid of the first parameter?

```
public List<int> Call<TEnum>(TEnum enumValue) 
{
    Type enumType = typeof(TEnum);

    // Something
}
```

Comment: A good solutions since it's impossible to do it my way. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Ohlin alternative solution in my update. See if that works for you.

Comment: My idea was to pass an enum and a given default value of that enum, but it can be any kind of enum. I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: Yes, the update works really well...this solution is actually better than the one I initially was thinking of! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I'd think of doing something similar is by adding a condition inside the function and either return something or throw an Exception if the parameter is wrong (with a clear explanation).